# Which scenarios allow to use Chef or Azure SDK to create VM and deploy in automation

Tags: c#, azure, automation, chef-infra, devops

There are two ways defined in the Microsoft site in order to create the azure VM.

1. [Creating from C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/csharp)
2. [Create using Chef](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/chef-automation)

I want to know what is the difference and what would be flexibility can be achieved using the process defined, as VM can also be managed from the Azure portal like Chef Server.

My scenario is to provide the complete automation in creating the azure VM and deploy the app package on it after installing the IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are like 10 different ways to create a VM in Azure (6 or so different SDK's, Powershell\Cli\Cli2\Rest Request\Arm Template\probably something else).

If chef can create a vm in Azure it is using one of those ways internally to do so. The main difference is what you have to know\do for one of the methods to work.

To automate app deployment to an Azure VM you can use different means (script extension\DSC\Ansible\Chef\puppet\etc).

Also, you question is too broad to be answered with more precision.